# JavaScript cannot compare values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var eTop = $(this).scrollTop()
    $('.popup').each(function(i){
        log(eTop);
        if($(this).offset().top - topLimit <= eTop){
            $(this).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
```

I got this [Fiddle](http://bit.ly/PQvkRw), where i want to use fadeIn() on elements, when they are 100 pixels from the top of the screen. I give JavaScript 3 values to use in comparison, to know when that should happen, but I doesn't work... I measured the values myself via a log-function I used, and it should work, but it just doesn't... I was hoping anyone maybe could see an error I cant... Thanks

Comment: Look logging both http://jsfiddle.net/D6tE2/4/

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the image is hidden, so `offsetTop` doesn't work.

Removing

```
.popup{
    display:none;
}
```

fixes it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6tE2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It can't work because:

```
var eTop = $(this).scrollTop()
```

and

```
$(this).offset().top
```

is the same value and your IF condition is never met.

Comment: No, `this` is used inside each loop

Comment: I have just run your fiddle with console outputting both those values and they are always the same.

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava is correct, the values are always the same because the element is `display:none`, which removes it from the DOM, giving it a 0 position.

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava I'm not OP ;) Ya, now i see what you mean, i didn't even see the first time the popup element

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your image is hidden, so offsetTop won't work as @Oriol point out. but you can get around with that by measuring the text height, because the image is just after the text. working version is this: http://jsfiddle.net/D6tE2/6/

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var eTop = $(this).scrollTop()
    $('.popup').each(function(i){
        if($('p').height() < eTop){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another solution](http://jsfiddle.net/D6tE2/10/)

There's really two problems at play here:

1: `display: none` takes your object out of the correct `DOM` position, so when your `img` is hidden, the calculation on its page offset is always the same as `scrollTop` (i.e., at `0,0` relative to the document root).

2: Even if you compensate for this by using something like `opacity: 0` - which places it in the correct place in the DOM, `fadeIn` expects `display: none` to be set, so we have to manually `hide()` the entry and reset it's `opacity`, then `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just animate it setting the opacity to 0 to start with. To have the same effect as display none, you can set the position to absolute at first. I also added a check for the show class so the code does not run again when it is already shown

http://jsfiddle.net/D6tE2/14/

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var eTop = $(this).scrollTop()
    $('.popup').each(function(i){
        log(eTop);
        if(!$(this).hasClass('show') && $(this).offset().top < eTop){
            $(this).addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.popup{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.show {
    position: static;
}
```